# Search for missing records for the week

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am having troubles with formulating a sql query to search for missing records for the week. I am using access 2007. The following shows the tables that i have.

```
Employee Table        
ID     Name  
1      JOhn  
2      Peter
```

---

```
Time Cards  
ID     Name     Date        Week        SO     CardNUm  
1      John     15/06/2015  21/06/2015  1234   1  
2      Peter    16/06/2015  21/06/2015  1233   2  
1      John     16/06/2015  21/06/2015  1231   3  
1      John     17/06/2015  21/06/2015  1230   4
```

I have managed to search for missing records for a particular day, using the following sql query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  
      Employee.Name  
      Employee.ID  
    FROM Employee
    WHERE (((Employee.Name) Not In (
SELECT TC.Name 
FROM [Time Card] AS TC 
WHERE TC.Name = Employee.Name AND TC.Date = [Forms]![Missing Production Time Card]![Text12] )));
```

I am trying to search for all records such that any days within a week eg 15/06/2015 to 21/06/2015 for a employee who did not key in their time cards.
Is there any way that i can modify my query or create a new one such that i get the following results?

The results for the above time card table should have

```
ID  Name Date  
1   John 18/06/2015  
1   John 19/06/2015  
1   John 20/06/2015  
1   john 21/06/2015  
2   Peter 15/06/2015  
2   Peter 17/06/2015  
2   Peter 18/06/2015  
2   Peter 19/06/2015  
2   Peter 20/06/2015  
2   Peter 21/06/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a temporary table, and populate it with the dates and employees you are searching for.  You can then use an `outer join` to join to the `Time Card` table, and any rows from your temp table that don't have a matching row in `Time Card` are missing.

It would be useful to have another table with a list of the dates for a particular week - this would make the below code slightly easier, and also allow you to deal with bank holidays and weekends.

Here's a stab at the code:

```
CREATE TABLE ##missing (
    Date datetime,
    ID int
)

INSERT ##missing SELECT '20150605', ID FROM Employee
-- Repeat for other dates in the week, or use the table proposed above

SELECT
    m.Date,
    e.Name
FROM ##missing m
JOIN Employee e
    ON m.ID = e.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Time Card] tc
    ON m.ID = tc.ID
    AND m.Date = tc.Date
WHERE tc.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: yes. Although i have thought about using a temporary table for that, but that would mean i will be the one to always create the temporary table to check for missing records. I have also tried to use between but realized it doesnt work the way i want.